# Evaluating $\int_\gamma \frac{1}{(z-4)^2}$ where $\gamma$ is the circle of radius 2 centered at $4+i$

Tags: complex-analysis

My first attempt was to deform the circle to the circle of radius 1 centered at $(4,0)$, and then compute the integral over this circle. Doing this gives me zero for the value of the integral, but is this actually correct? Much thanks for anyone that can confirm this! :)

Comment: You don't need to do any deformation; just use the residue theorem.

Comment: I'm afraid that I cannot use the residue theorem at this point. Is deformation still valid?

Comment: @AndreaM111 Believe the deformation is valid.

Comment: @AndreaM111 In principle, yes, but how are you using deformation without knowing the residue theorem? The statement that you can deform contours without changing the value as long as the deformation doesn't pass through a pole is pretty much 90% of the residue theorem...

Answer (score 0):

$$\oint_\gamma\frac1{(z-4)^2}dz=0$$

which is trivial, since the integrand is of the form

$$f(z)=\dots+\frac{c_{-3}}{(z-4)^3}+\frac{c_{-2}}{(z-4)^2}+\boxed{\frac{c_{-1}}{z-4}}+c_0+c_1(z-4)+\dots$$

And any contour integral enclosing $z=4$ has

$$\oint_\gamma f(z)dz=2\pi ic_{-1}$$

Comment: It seems that OP is not going to accept a good hint. +1

Comment: @Jack Apparently the case with all these `(complex-analysis)` questions.